# Why map generated during stream operation on list is not in order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

input :

```
RTYUUJKIOO
```

actul output :

```
--R--1
--T--1
--U--2
--Y--1
--I--1
--J--1
--K--1
--O--2
```

expected output :

```
--R--1
--T--1
--Y--1
--U--2
--J--1
--K--1
--I--1
--O--2
```

Not sure why during printing order is not maintained.

Logic is below :

```
static String isValid(String s) 
{
    boolean validString;
    Map<String, Integer> characterFrequencyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    String[] singleLetterStringArray = s.split("");
    List<String> singleLetterStringList = Arrays.asList(singleLetterStringArray);
    singleLetterStringList.stream().forEachOrdered(l -> {
        Integer frequency;
        if(characterFrequencyMap.containsKey(l)) {
            frequency = characterFrequencyMap.get(l);
            characterFrequencyMap.put(l, frequency + 1);
        } else {
            characterFrequencyMap.put(l, 1);
        }
    });
    Set<String> keys = characterFrequencyMap.keySet();
    Iterator<String> keyItr = keys.iterator();
    while(keyItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keyItr.next();
        System.out.print("--" + key + "--");
        System.out.println(characterFrequencyMap.get(key));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, there is no need to deal with an `Iterator` manually here. You can just write `for(String key: characterFrequencyMap.keySet()) System.out.println("--"+key+"--"+ characterFrequencyMap.get(key));` but iterating over the keys to perform a `get` operation for each key is unnecessarily inefficient. You can iterate over the entry set instead: `for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry: characterFrequencyMap.entrySet()) System.out.println("--"+entry.getKey()+"--"+ entry.getValue());` Or Java 8’s alternative: `characterFrequencyMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("--"+k+"--"+v);`…

Comment: Good points @Holger. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` doesn't maintain insertion order. If you want to maintain insertion order, use `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Map<String, Integer> characterFrequencyMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

BTW, a better way to generate this `Map` with `Stream`s is using `collect()`:

```
Map<String,Long> characterFrequencyMap =
    singleLetterStringList.stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (Function.identity (),
                                                          LinkedHashMap::new,
                                                          Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Thanks @Eran. Your solution is clean.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that `HashMap` does not maintain insertion order instead use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Further, splitting the string into an array then converting it to a list before performing the necessary operations is suboptimal, you could use the `chars()` method directly on the string and then start performing the necessary operations.

Using the stream API, one could do:

```
 Map<String, Long> resultSet = 
               s.chars()
                .mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
                .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        LinkedHashMap::new, counting()));
```